# How do I conduct an exact test to test if 3 levels of an outcome are equal to certain proportions in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have 3 levels of depression in my data with the following observed frequencies: none (481), minor (136), and major (128). I want to test if the proportions of the 3 levels in my data are = 0.5, 0.3, and 0.2 respectively.

To do a chi-squared test in R, I did

```
chisq.test(x = c(481, 136, 128),
           p = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2))
```

which gave me this output

```
Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  c(481, 136, 128)
X-squared = 68.819, df = 2, p-value = 1.138e-15
```

I want to also do an exact test. I tried

```
fisher.test(x = c(481, 136, 128),
            y = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2))
```

which gives me this

```
Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  c(481, 136, 128) and c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)
p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: in `chisq.test()`  you are using the `p` input for the probabilities but `fisher.test()` does not have that input and you are using `y` instead which is not the same.

Comment: Great thanks. What should I do instead for the fisher.test() ?

Comment: can you tell me what the proportions represent?

Comment: Theoretical population proportions of depression. We're trying to see if our data has the same proportions of depression as the theoretical population.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best way to do this, but a workaround is doing the fischer.test() with observed counts in one column and expected counts in another like this:

```
obs_exp <- matrix(c(481, 136, 128, 745 * 0.5, 745 * 0.3, 745 * 0.2), 3, 2)
obs_exp

     [,1]  [,2]
[1,]  481 372.5
[2,]  136 223.5
[3,]  128 149.0

fisher.test(obs_exp)

Warning in fisher.test(obs_exp) :
  'x' has been rounded to integer: Mean relative difference: 0.001677852

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  obs_exp
p-value = 8.152e-09
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do a similar test is to use `prop.test()`. I put the vector of successes in first, then the probabilities to test them against, and then the sample size in the n (the same length as x and n is the sum of x ). I would check the help documentation of ?prop.test for more information on the test.

```
prop.test(x =c(481,136,128), p = c(.5,.3,.2), n = c(745,745,745))
```

Comment: Thanks - that gives the Chi-squared test for the proportions, but I'm looking for the exact test. From the documentation of prop.test(), they suggested binom.test() for the exact test. However, this only handles one proportion at a time ``` binom.test(x = 481, n = 745, p = 0.5) ```

Comment: it sounds like from the data you have an exact test might not be possible. is there a reason you need to perform that test?

Comment: Honestly it's for an assignment! I wouldn't be doing it otherwise. I think there's an easy way to do this in SAS but I haven't been able to directly translate it to R